# Pydrake can't import common.test_utilities.deprecation

Tags: drake

I am running `plant_test.py` of pydrake in [plant_test.py](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/multibody/test/plant_test.py)
I have downloaded drake from source code, and made it successfully.
But I can't import these moduld

```
from pydrake.common.test_utilities import numpy_compare
from pydrake.common.test_utilities.deprecation import catch_drake_warnings
from pydrake.common.test_utilities.pickle_compare import assert_pickle
```

Here is the detailed terminal output

```
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
    raise self._exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: MAIN2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/yuxuan/Project/ProsSimu/ProsSimu/on_windows/MAIN2.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pydrake.common.test_utilities import numpy_compare
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake.common.test_utilities'
```

I searched the `make -j`  output, and there is no word about test_utilities.
Hope anyone can help me, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Drake's unit tests are for the benefit of its development team, and generally rely on test modules and infrastructure beyond what is part of Drake's CMake-installed files intended for end users.

To run Drake's tests, you must use the same development tools as the Drake maintainers.  See https://drake.mit.edu/bazel.html for instructions.

From a source checkout, to run the python multibody tests for example:

```
bazel test //bindings/pydrake/multibody/...
```

If you goal is to learn how to use Drake, rather than how to contribute new code to Drake, then https://drake.mit.edu/#tutorials is probably a better starting point than the unit tests.

Comment: Thanks so much. I searched this code because I want to load a urdf humanoid model, which needs pherical joints. Is there any kind of joint types in drake can help me to do the character simulation using motion capture data? Anyway,  thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: Drake has a [BallRpyJoint](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_ball_rpy_joint.html) that implements a gimbal joint (spherical, but one can have rpy singularities).  We [intend to have a quaternion version](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12404), too. It looks like we don't parse from sdf's "ball" joint type into the BallRpyJoint yet -- if you need that then please scribble on that issue.

Comment: I was mistaken.  We do currently parse "ball" in sdf (and urdf) into the BallRpyJoint.